# List the partitions of the set $S = \{1, 2, 3\}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-partition

I write the partition sets of set $S=\{1,2,3\}$ as follows:

$\{\{1, 2, 3\},
\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}\}$

can someone show me why and how to complete the list?

Comment: What about $\{ 1, 2 \}, \{2, 3\}$ and $\{3, 1\}$?

Comment: A partition of $S$ is a collection of nonempty subsets of $S$ which are pairwise disjoint and whose union is $S$. You didn't really write a partition of $S$. Two example of partitions of $S$ are $\left\{\{1,2\},\{3\}\right\}$ and $\left\{\{1,2,3\}\right\}$ (this is just $\{S\}$). Try to find all other ones.

Comment: so my answer should be like this, S={1,2,3}

={{1,2,3},

{1},{2},{3}

{1,2},{3},

{1},{2,3},

{1,3},{2},}. I'm I correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the OP said in his comment the answer is the following list of partitions of $S = \{1,2,3\}$:

1. $\left\{ \{1,2,3\} \right\}$ (one set, just $S$ itself )
2. $\left\{ \{1,2\}, \{3\} \right\}$ (two sets, one of two elements , one singleton)
3. $\left\{ \{1,3\}, \{2\} \right\}$
4. $\left\{ \{2,3\}, \{1\} \right\}$
5. $\left\{ \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\} \right\}$ (all singletons)

and these are all.